# Navigation using objects and arrays with Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need to set up a navigation using this data and Underscore.

There are two headings with 5 links in each.

This is the way I have my data and I cannot get Underscore to work and bring all the links and labels, can anyone please help?

```
var navigations = [{
    "main_label": "GIRLS",
    "sub_page_reference": "girls",
    "links": [{
        "label": "NEW IN >",
        "href": "/uk/newin",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "sales >",
        "href": "/uk/salesy",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "girls >",
        "href": "/uk/girls",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "boys >",
        "href": "/uk/boys",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "party >",
        "href": "/uk/party",
        "target": "_self",
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "main_label": "BOYS",
    "sub_page_reference": "boys",
    "links": [{
        "label": "NEW IN >",
        "href": "/uk/newin",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "sales >",
        "href": "/uk/salesy",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "girls >",
        "href": "/uk/girls",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "boys >",
        "href": "/uk/boys",
        "target": "_self",
      },

      {
        "label": "party >",
        "href": "/uk/party",
        "target": "_self",
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: That's a collection of JavaScript literals (and a variable) not JSON. Since you don't appear to be calling `_()` at any point, it isn't surprising that it doesn't "bring all the links and labels"… whatever that means.

Comment: sorry I dont understand what you mean by this?

Comment: @charlie97 look up the definition of JSON. It's a string, not JavaScript code like you have there. The other question is what do you actually want to do with the underscore code? What is your expected output? I'll try and cobble together an answer and see if it's close to what you're looking for...

Comment: @charlie97 — You have not clearly described what you want to achieve. You have not shown us the code that you are using to try to achieve that. You have not told us what behaviour you actually get (and how that differs from what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: sorry if i was not clear, in this nav bar, there will be two headings and those 5 links within them. My whole page is with JSON and underscore JS so this is just part of it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a JSFiddle that gets an array of links and labels, then uses an underscore template to output to the page: https://jsbin.com/joqika/1/edit?html,js,output

Get array of links and labels using underscore:

```
var l = _.map(navigation, function(item) {
  return item.links;
});

var linksFlat = _.reduceRight(l, function(a, b) { 
  return a.concat(b); 
}, []);
```

Use a template to output to page:

```
var templ = _.template('<% _.each(links, function(l) { %><li><a href="<%= l.href %>"><%= l.label %></a></li> <% }); %>');

var compiled = templ({links: linksFlat});

$('.js-links').html(compiled);
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin OK mate, fixed.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I could see the results which was correct but I cant see any of the underscore JS code it keeps giving me failed message.

Comment: @charlie97 you can see it working on the fiddle? In what way can't you see it?  What error are you seeing exactly? Have you actually included the reference to the underscore library in your HTML?

Comment: <script type="text/template"  id="navigation_links">
<ul>
 <li>
<@ _.each( data , function(item, index){ @> 
<h3> <@= item.main_label @> </h3>
<a href='<@= item.links[0].href @>' target='<@= item.links[0].target @>' >
<p> <@= item.links[0].label @> </p>
  
</a> 
<@ }); @>   
 </li> 
</ul>

this is what I currently have and it only brings the first link within each of the heading


</script>

Comment: @charlie97 why the ... isn't that in your question!? All I can say is that my approach works, try using it and then put back bits of your code.

Answer (score -2):

just made it work, I needed a for loop in there:
<@ for (i = 0; i < item.links.length; i++) {  @>
 ....
<@ } @>

Comment: why would I be getting a negative point for answering it correctly? HAH